# What is a good way for getter to setter mapping from simple java objects (POJOs). Can is use reflection for it?

Tags: java, reflection, mapping, pojo

Hi i have two java objects, which are independent to each other, but share the same **getter** and **setter** methods. For example, I have an **UserEntity** and **UserDTO** object and I will map all getter values from the UserEntity to all setter of the UserDTO.

What is the best way of doing such kind of things? I prefer to do it with java reflection, but I also would like to now if there are some useful framework implementations outside.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a great mapper library called [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/) which can used to map.

Here an example for your UserEntity and UserDTO:

```
@Mapper
public interface UserMapper {

    UserMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(UserMapper.class);

    @Mapping
    UserDTO userEntityToUserDTO(UserEntity user); 
}

UserDTO userDto = UserMapper.INSTANCE.userEntityToUserDTO(userEntity);
```

It also supports conversion between compatible types and it's also possible to set custom mappings if fields aren't named the same. For example:

```
@Mapping(source = "userName", target = "name")
```

Answer (score 3):

This need is usually best implemented with a "converter" or "mapper" pattern. My preferred tool for generating mappers in Java is [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/), but a number of others exist.

Using reflection is not generally the best option both because it's slower and because it's much more difficult to track and customize (for example, if fields need to be converted between strings in JSON and `long`s in Java).

Answer (score 2):

**With Reflection And Without Using External Library**

Hi you can inspect the source object for all its getter's and the try to find all corresponding setters on the target object. The following Method should do it:

```
 /**
 * Maps all getter of the source to all corresponding setter of the target
 * @param target
 *      target object which should be set
 * @param source
 *      source object to read from
 * @return
 *      returns mapped target object or null if some error occurred
 */
private Object getterToSetter(Object target, Object source) {
    try {
        for(Method m: source.getClass().getMethods()){
            // try to find for all getters in the source the corresponding setter on the target
            if(m.getName().startsWith("get")){
                Method setter;
                try {
                    setter = target.getClass().getMethod("set" + m.getName().substring(3), m.getReturnType());
                    setter.invoke(target,m.invoke(source));
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                    //ignored target just haven't a setter for this field
                }
            }
        }
        // return value to support builder pattern
        return target;
    }catch (IllegalAccessException| InvocationTargetException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here is a full Main.class example to the how it works:

```
    import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

/**
 * @author Andreas Hauschild
 */
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity().setName("Waltraud").setLastName("Schmidt").setPassword("TopSecret");
        UserDTO dto = (UserDTO) getterToSetter(new UserDTO(), userEntity);
        System.out.println(dto.getName());      //  prints "Waltraud"
        System.out.println(dto.getLastName());  //  prints "Schmidt"
    }

    /**
     * Maps all getter of the source to all corresponding setter of the target
     * @param target
     *      target object which should be set
     * @param source
     *      source object to read from
     * @return
     *      returns mapped target object or null if some error occurred
     */
    private static Object getterToSetter(Object target, Object source) {
        try {
            for(Method m: source.getClass().getMethods()){
                // try to find for all getters in the source the corresponding setter on the target
                if(m.getName().startsWith("get")){
                    Method setter;
                    try {
                        setter = target.getClass().getMethod("set" + m.getName().substring(3), m.getReturnType());
                        setter.invoke(target,m.invoke(source));
                    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                        //ignored target just haven't a setter for this field
                    }
                }
            }
            // return value to support builder pattern
            return target;
        }catch (IllegalAccessException| InvocationTargetException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static class UserEntity {
        String password;
        String name;
        String lastName;

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public UserEntity setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
            return this;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public UserEntity setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            return this;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public UserEntity setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
            return this;
        }
    }

    public static class UserDTO {
        String name;
        String lastName;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public UserDTO setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            return this;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public UserDTO setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
            return this;
        }
    }

}
```